# How to list the answer of Fitting Parameter?

Tags: fitting

I want to ask how to list the fitting parameter, using "Find Fit"?

I have data such as,

```
 lists ={{{2, 3}, {4.1, 1.2}, {5.3, 3.1}, {8., 10.5}}, {{2, 1}, {4.1, 0}, {5.4, 2}, {8.3, 6}}, {{1, 8.3}, {3.5, 2}, {5.5, 1.9}, {10, 6.1}}}
```

The list I want is

```
 coefficients = {{0.489728, -3.622667, 8.19737}, {0.225141, -1.48628, 2.91705}, {0.290042, -3.39467, 11.1431}}
```

But now the way I can derive the list "coefficients" by following,

```
ClearAll;
list1 = {{2, 3}, {4.1, 1.2}, {5.3, 3.1}, {8.0, 10.5}};
FindFit[list1, a1*x1^2 + a2*x1 + a3, {a1, a2, a3}, x1]
 ans1 = %


 ClearAll;
 list2 = {{2, 1}, {4.1, 0}, {5.4, 2}, {8.3, 6}};
 FindFit[list2, a4*x2^2 + a5*x2 + a6, {a4, a5, a6}, x2]
 ans2 = %


 ClearAll;
 list3 = {{1, 8.3}, {3.5, 2}, {5.5, 1.9}, {10, 6.1}};
 FindFit[list3, a7*x3^2 + a8*x3 + a9, {a7, a8, a9}, x3]
 ans3 = %

 coefficients = {ans1,ans2,ans3}
```

The above code will be OK if the number of list is small (i.e. this time only 3 lists), however, if I have more lists, it will be troublesome. I think defying coefficients as "a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9" is not sophisticated. I tried to make function but it didn't work. If someone knows smarter ways to write, please please tell me.
Moreover, the last code which I wrote includes characters such as "a1 ->", which I'm struggling to get rid of...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a function that takes an input list of `{x,y}` pairs and returns three coefficients (named `a`, `b`, and `c`)

```
ClearAll[fitCoefficients]
fitCoefficients[inputdata_] := {a, b, c} /. 
    FindFit[inputdata, a x^2 + b x + c, {a, b, c}, x]
```

You can [`Map`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html) the function `fitCoefficients` on `lists`

```
coefficients = fitCoefficients /@ lists
```

> ```
> {{0.489728, -3.62267, 8.19737}, 
>  {0.225141, -1.48628, 2.91705}, 
>  {0.290042, -3.39467, 11.1431}}
> ```

Alternatively, you can use [`Table`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html) to iterate over the data sets in `lists`:

```
coefficients = Table[fitCoefficients[lists[[i]]], {i, Length@lists}]
```

> ```
> same result
> ```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I always grateful to you for being such a great teacher. The explanation is very easy to understand. I didn't know the way to map the function and usage of Table in this way. Thanks again.

Comment: @nancy, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.

Comment: You are always so warm-hearted! Thank you VERY much.